# How do I store a reference to a generic type created based on an expression passed to the method?

Tags: c#, generics, expression

I have the following method, which returns a generic object of type `INamedProperty<TReturn>` based on the return type of a defined expression. I need to store a reference to the object that is returned by this method for future processing. What type should I store it as? Would `Object` be OK? How would I cast it back to the appropriate `INamedProperty<TReturn>` later on? Do I also need to store the type of `TReturn`?

```
public class PropertyBuilder<T> : IPropertyBuilder<T> where T : class {
    public INamedProperty<TReturn> Named<TReturn>(Expression<Func<T, TReturn>> property) {
        o = new NamedProperty<TReturn>();
        // how do I store o as an instance of the encapsulating class?
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume `T` is the type argument to the enclosing class?

Comment: Yes. Apologies for not clarifying that. I'll provide some more context in my question.

Comment: How will you use this object in future processing? If an object reference is sufficient, just use that. What happens if the generic method Named is called first as Named<A>, then as Named<B>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would *try* to implement a generic, uhh, **non**-generic `INamedProperty` that could implement the operations you need:

```
interface INamedProperty
{
    // Informational
    Type ContainingType { get; }
    string Name { get; }
    Type ReturnType { get; }

    // Operations (for example)
    void CopyTo(object obj, INamedProperty property);
}
```

Then implement them in the generic NamedProperty:

```
class NamedProperty<T> : INamedProperty { ... }
```

Comment: This is what I ended up going with. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

Why not take an additional Action parameter instead of storing a reference?  You're running into trouble because TReturn doesn't really exist in a concrete form outside the context of your method's execution; think more functional programming and less procedural.

edit: added code sample

```
public INamedProperty<TReturn> Named<TReturn>(Expression<Func<T, TReturn>> property, Action<INamedProperty<TReturn>> action)
{
    var o = new NamedProperty<TReturn>();
    action.Invoke(o);
    return o;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this, please?

Comment: Are you aware C# lets you just call delegates, you don't need to use `Invoke()`? eg: `action(o);`, `ret = func(a);`.